# Need help?? Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, maven-release-plugin

i want to deploy my maven project to Google Appengine, however an error in that

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @HospitalReservationSystem ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/rof/src/github.com/jessezzyy/Hospital-Reservation-System/target/HospitalReservationSystem-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.062 s [INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-26T15:17:24Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project HospitalReservationSystem: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
```

The maven project is exactly using java8, and my java jdk is also 1.8enter image description here

```
ZIJIANdeMacBook-Pro:JavaVirtualMachines Jesse$ echo $JAVA_HOME/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/HomeZIJIANdeMacBook-Pro:JavaVirtualMachines Jesse$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

I have tried to change 1.7 instead of 1.8, but it shows error:

```
Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make sure that you have Java 8 and its corresponding compiler installed.

Test that by executing the following code:

```
java -version
```

and

```
 javac -version
```

and

```
 mvn -version
```

They should be the same version. Sometimes the java is pointing to the right version but javac version might point to an old jdk. If this is the case, you can apply the following steps:

A:Ensure the symbolic link is pointing to the correct jdk. if not, just remove it and recreate a new one for your jdk.
Code:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
rm CurrentJDK
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<jdk version>.jdk/Contents/ CurrentJDK
```

B:Remove the tools.jar from the extension since it could be related to the old version:
Code:

```
cd /Library/Java/Extensions
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  15286304 Jan 14  2015 tools.jar
```

Remove this:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/Extensions
```

In addition, you also need to make sure you %JAVA_HOME is set to 1.8 once you install the 1.8 jdk. Keep in mind that Invalid target release refers to the jdk version.

Another solution is to fork the maven-compiler-plugin and set the full path to the correct Java compiler as below:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_79\bin\javac</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This issue has already been posted along with useful answers and possible solutions to your question: [Click Here](https:////stackoverflow.com/questions/28291691/fatal-error-compiling-invalid-target-release-1-8-help-1)

Here is another question previously posted regarding the same issue: [Click Here](https:////stackoverflow.com/questions/31591540/maven-fatal-error-compiling-invalid-target-release-1-8)

Comment: sorry it is also not working for me. i changed source and target version to 1.7 and i got new error :  goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1

Comment: In this case the more information, the better we can tackle the issue. It would be easier to narrow down the problem if you could provide more details such as your full log from your failed deployment and some relevant configuration files. Also, are you deploying it in Standard or Flex environment?

Answer (score 1):

Though this is pretty old post, I thought I will share my quick fix for others use:
I also had faced similar issue where pom.xml is pointing 1.8 and JAVA_HOME is also pointing to 1.8
Maven build was failing through eclipse.

To address this issue, all I had to do is change the JRE version to 1.8 in JRE tab using Alternate JRE option as shown in attached [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsDW9.png).